# How to add drop-down list & toggle switch columns into migration table columns in PHP Laravel？

Tags: php, laravel

I am use PHP with Laravel framework.

In my front-end page, my table contains information for link, comment, date, number, toggle switch etc

Now for my back-end, I am adding columns into the table under migration folder.
I know how to add the type for my link(`$table->string('my_link');`), comment(`$table->text('my_comments');`), date(`$table->dateTime('my_date');`)number ( `$table->decimal('my_number',20,3);`) etc

But I am not sure which type under https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations should I choice for **toggle switch** and **drop-dwon list** data.

Is it reasonable if I use **Boolean** to save **toggle switch** data? For example  `$table->boolean('confirmed');`

And is it reasonable if I use
`$table->integer('my_drop_down_list')->unsigned();`
`$table->foreign('my_drop_down_list')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('NO ACTION')->onDelete('NO ACTION');`to save **drop-down list** data?

Comment: yes you can use boolean or tinyint to store value in 1/0 form 1 form confirm and 0 for not confirmed. Similarly if your drop down list contain items from another table then you can use that table PK as FK in this table

Comment: @AqibJaved Thank you so much! Would you mind give me an example? That would be more visible. For example, so far my boolean is ```$table->boolean('confirmed');``` how can I assign 1 for confirm and 0 for not confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a toggle button in your form like this.

```
<input  class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" name="confirmed">
```

In your controller you will check if toggle button is `on` or `Off`.

```
$confirmed = $request->confirmed? 1:0; // 1 if toggle  on 0 if off

$model->confirmed = $confirmed;  // replace $model  with name of your model
$model->save() or $model->update();
```

**Note : Update variables according to your code.**

Comment: Thank you! Before I go to **controller** folder, is there anything I need to write under **migration** folder or **model**?

Comment: you can replace $table->boolean('confirmed'); with $table->tinyint('confirmed'); if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this into your table:

`country_id` field is big integer - foreign key in the table.
`confirmed` field is enum datatype in the table.

```
Schema::create('states', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('country_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->enum('confirmed',['0','1'])->default('0');
    $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```